# Sign a User certificate with CA.key :openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates

I've a user certificate (`certname.pem`) and user key (`keyname.pem`) which I've generated using the command below.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout keyname.pem -x509 -days 365 -out certname.pem
```

Also I've generated a CA key (`ca.key.pem`) and CA root certificate (`ca.root.pem`) using the command below.

```
openssl req -x509 -days 557 -newkey rsa:1024 -out ca.root.pem -keyout ca.key.pem
```

Now I want to sign the user certificate (`certname.pem`) with the CA key (`ca.key.pem`) but I am unable to do so using the command below.

```
openssl ca -create_serial -config openssl.cnf -cert ca.root.pem -keyfile ca.key.pem -in certname.pem  -out new-certname.pem
```

as this command gives error:

```
Error reading certificate request in certname.pem
139992806578040:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:708:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST
```

Where as the contents of my certname.pem are as follows:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How to sign this certificate with the ca.key.pem?
Please help.

Reference for generating certificates - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWHYP_4.0.0/com.ibm.apimgmt.cmc.doc/task_apionprem_gernerate_self_signed_openSSL.html

Comment: A certificate is already signed. What a CA instead needs as input for signing is a certificate request and the error message clearly says so: "Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST". Only you gave a certificate and not a certificate request. Apart from that, don't [cross post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189148/sign-a-user-certificate-with-ca-key-openssl) to multiple sites.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, corss posted to multiple sites as was in urgent need of solution and wasn't getting it. Will not do this thing in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question originally answered by - https://stackoverflow.com/users/99027/john-deters
on https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189148/sign-a-user-certificate-with-ca-key-openssl

You included `-out certname.pem` on your original request, which in this case instructed openssl to generate a self-signed root CA certificate named certname.pem. It is a certificate, but probably not the kind you want here.

I assume you instead want to use your newly minted CA to sign your public key and create a server certificate. You'll need to first generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) from your new key (the one in `keyname.pem`):

```
openssl req -out keyname.csr -key keyname.pem -new -days 365
```

You can then pass this CSR to request a certificate:

```
openssl ca -create_serial -config openssl.cnf -cert ca.root.pem -keyfile ca.key.pem -in keyname.csr -out new-certname.pem
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is - CA signs a CSR (certificate signing request) and as a result is a completely new certificate issued by the CA

I have some examples ready for myself https://pastebin.com/m9rzFJ9c

```
#create certificate signing request
openssl req -new -key ./sslCA/private/myserver.key -out ./sslCA/private/cakey.csr
#sign the signing request
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ./sslCA/private/cakey.csr -signkey ./sslCA/private/myserver.key -out 
./sslCA/private/cacert.pem
```